# second live updating graph not updating with multiple d3 charts

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, d3.js, live

Has any one ever had the problem of running two live updating graphs in two separate html containers and only one of the graphs updates with new data? When only one graph is on the page (either graph) it all works, but when there are two, both graphs work (they are interactive) but one doesn't update with live data?

I use d3 to generate two charts as two objects and put each one in a separate container (I have a separate script for generating the chart called SomeChart.js) and then call the update data method on each chart:

I run two of the following code to create to variables: firstChart (in container ID FirstChartContainerID') secondChart (in container ID SecondChartContainerID')

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.time = parseDate(d.time);
        d.data = +d.data;
    });
    var firstChart = new SomeChart('FirstChartContainerID', data);    
    setInterval(function(){
        d3.csv("updatingdata.csv", function(error, newData) {
            firstChart.updateData(newData);
        });    
    }, 30000);
});
```

and then update each chart using the 'update' method in SomeChart.js

```
this.updateData = function(newData) {
    j = data.length;
    for(i = 0; i < newData.length; i++){
        data[j] = {"time": parseDate(newData[i].time), "data": +(newData[i].data)}
        j++;
    }
    redrawAxesContext(true); redrawYAxesFocus(true);
    redrawLines();
    $(container).trigger('LineGraph:dataModification')
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a scoping problem or something similar where one of the graphs isn't referenced properly. We'll have to see the entire code (preferably in something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) to help you further.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I found the error, it wasn't to do with the graphs not being referenced correctly. It was to do with that I was testing the incoming data using 'if/else if statement', but forgot a third 'else' condition. Since the data usually fits in the third 'else' condition, it didn't get added and thus the graph didn't get updated.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting jsfiddle and replying @LarsKotthoff! I will do that next time!